# Finding the Difference of the days in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table detail is :

```
Date                ORGUnitCode SKUId   LocationID  LP  DivisionCode    DeptCode    CategoryCode    OPBalQty    OPBalValue  Sync    
2013-03-31 00:00:00 DELG14  10059764    107       432.55    G           MN          KLO             0.00            0.00    0   
2013-03-31 00:00:00 DELG14  10063213    107       699.05    G           MN          KLO             0.00            0.00    0   
2013-03-31 00:00:00 DELG14  10090728    107       250.76    G           MN          PYJ             0.00            0.00    0
```

Here `OPBalQty` is either **1.00** or **0.00** in a huge number of records.

I want to find out the number of the days since `OPBalQty` is **0.00** for all available `SKUId`, rephrasing it to be find particular skuId that is stockOut for the number of the days. I have tried to find it but not working can anyone point to this?

Comment: Your title and description doesn't help.Can you please add some sample data and show expected result

Comment: Added some data from the actual table.

Comment: Your example data has all 0.00 as the value you are referencing. Trying adding some additional data and then some example output e.g. the number of days you would expect.  Also do you want the number of consecutive days that the value has been 0.00 since the last time it was 1.00 or the number of consecutive days the value has been 1.00 since the last time it was 0.00

Comment: @Matt, You think of a single item that adds a row everyday in database and while adding this record OPBalQty is either 0.00 that mean there is not stock for this item and 1.00 that mean there is 1 Quantity of this item and so on. Notice that for some old days(that mean for some old rows) this OPBalQty can be 0.00 but after that it may get greater than 0.00. So, all I want is the number of the days since stock was 0.00 in latest time.

Comment: I think myself and others understand your desire it is is the nuances that can creep into the answer.  Such as you want number of days but is that number of records in your database or the datediff() of the date field between the last 0.00 and the current record or current date?

Comment: I want to calc the difference when latest date in DATE column of the table has OpBalQty '0.00'(Stock was last unavailable) upto the last time of any previous date's OpBalQty has greater than 0.00(Stock was last available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment I believe this is the answer you're looking for. Hopefully you can see these are variations on the same theme and you can adapt it as necessary.

```
select
    SKUId,
    datediff(
        day,
        max(case when OPBalQty = 1 then "Date" end),
        max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" end)
    ) as NumDays

from T
group by SKUId
having max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" end) = max("Date")
```

---

**Previous Answer**

If you just want to get the latest date with a zero `OPBalQty` then you're just looking for the `max()` date which you can use for the difference calculation.

```
select
    SKUId,
    datediff(day, getdate(), max("Date")) as NumDays
from T
where OPBalQty = 0
group by SKUId
```

If you're only looking for SKUs that are zero in the latest date you can use a variety of checks in a `having` clause.

```
select
    SKUId,
    datediff(day, getdate(), max("Date") as NumDays
from T
group by SKUId
having max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" end) = max("Date")
-- this condition would also work if it seems clearer
-- max(case when OPBalQty=0 then "Date" end) > max(case when OPBalQty=1 then "Date" end)
```

And of course if you need to only see those SKUs where the date difference is greater than some number of days just add that condition to the `having` as well.

```
select
    SKUId,
    datediff(day, getdate(), max("Date")) as NumDays
from T
group by SKUId
having  max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" end) = max("Date")
    and datediff(day, getdate(), max("Date")) >= X
```

Comment: I think we are done with it. The middle one, thanks. But this will be executing over 600 million rows can you suggest some optimization

Comment: @TraDev:I recommend running the query and see it it runs slow,if it runs slow,post the execution plan,schema of table,indexes and ask as a seperate question

Comment: @TraDev Perhaps you want to add `where "Date" >= '20160101'` or something. If you were certain that you couldn't have had anything out of stock for that entire time it would probably improve the query, assuming indexes and all that.

Comment: @shawnt00, exactly this was the business problem I wanted to solve. I have customized it on my requirement and updated here, thanks! As my table is here so I want to extent this question to capture those date which I have just counted but only 30 date ( latest date and may be in single variable).

Comment: @TraDev I don't quite understand but it almost sounds like you want `where "Date" >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())` or `where "Date" >= @startDate`.

Comment: @shawnt00, I want to pick the particular date from the DATE Column in my table in a single string format with coma separated. Note that I want only MAX 30 date upon same criteria as we followed in just resolved query.

Comment: @TraDev If you only want thirty days I've already offered that suggestion. I don't understand what formats and commas have to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Pointed solution to the discussed problem :

```
select distinct SKUId,
        datediff( day,
        max(case when OPBalQty > 0 then "Date" end),
        max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" when OPBalQty = -1 then "Date" end)) as NumDays
    from Admin.Stocks
    group by SKUId
    having max(case when OPBalQty = 0 then "Date" end) = max("Date")
```